# SHChangeNotify for cloud folders fails with long paths

Tags: c#, windows-shell

We have an application that is using the Cloud File Api to implement a OneDrive like product.   The following workflow causes a problem

**STEPS**

1. Navigate to a folder in windows explorer
2. On another machine or via a web client, rename the folder that you are viewing in step 1
3. Program receives a notification from the server that the folder has been renamed

**What we do in response**

4. Update the local operation system with a move/rename to reflect the server
5. Use SHChangeNotify to tell the operating system that the folder was renamed

**What I expect to happen**

The address bar in windows explorer is updated to the new name

**What actually happens**

The address bar will be updated in normal circumstances. However, if the path to the folder was > 260 characters, then the address bar is updated as shown bellow with the "\?" prefix as shown below

This might seem harmless but it is not because explorer behaves very badly when the explorer bar has that prefix.  Most IO operations (ie. drag drop, etc) are either not allowed or don't work as expected.

It should also be noted that this is really only a problem if the folder being updated is the folder that is being viewed in explorer.

[image: Faulty address bar]

**Code Sample**

The code below represents what we are doing, GetExtendedPath() will append a "\?" in front of the path. This works for IO functions but doesn't have an affect on SHChangeNotify, it seems

```
Kernel32.MoveFile(oldPath.GetExtendedPath(), newPath.GetExtendedPath());
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER, SHCNF.SHCNF_PATHW, oldPath, newPath);
```

**Workarounds**

- I have tried to notify using the PIDLS, but that didn't update the explorer address bar with the new path
- for long path folders, i have tried sending an UPDATEDIR notification to the parent folder instead of the RENAMEFOLDER notification. This works in that explorer doesn't get put in a bad state, but the user is bounced out of the folder they are viewing in explorer and taken to the parent folder.  It's not the end of the world but, not ideal.

Any ideas for alternate approaches for handling this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Most of the Shell (and SHChangeNotify is no exception) supports only MAX_PATH paths (not MAX_PATH per segment like NTFS), so the best is clearly to always use PIDLs, not paths. If it doesn't seem to work with PIDLs, it's usally because PIDLs are not valid or do not correspond to what we think. That being said, when working with physical file paths (like when mimicking OneDrive), you shouldn't need to notify the Shell, it watches paths by itself.

Comment: @SimonMourier I find that everything does work mostly fine without needing the SHChangeNotify.  The exception seems to be this one case where
1. I have a folder open in explorer
2. I rename that folder

The address bar does not update to the new folder name.  With the SHChangeNotify, it will update but only with short paths.